# OSS projects that use "swiftest" ReactiveCocoa 3 API

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-cocoa-3

Evidently, in a process of wrapping my head around this FRP concept I need something more than a bare documentation. It's not an exaggeration to say that I'm struggling developing mental way of managing problems using the paradigm after I've been writing applications in imperative way for the last 4 years.

Could someone give me a few links on projects that use Swift RAC3 API? I'd be grateful if it were some iOS projects specifically.

Thanks.

Comment: Answering my own question, here's a simple yet elegant example of using latest RAC4 in Swift https://github.com/s0mmer/TodaysReactiveMenu